# Classes accessing each other with pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm still confused with pointers, maybe you could enlighten me a bit.

I'm having some classes pointing to each other and don't get the way to access them in the right way.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Player;
class Trainer;
class Team {
    Trainer* trainer_;
    std::vector<Player*> player_;
public:
    std::vector<Player*> player() { return player_; }
    Trainer* trainer() { return trainer_; }

    std::vector<Player*> get_playerlist(){
        return player_;
    };
};

class Player {
public: 

    void setteam_(Team* x){
        team_ = x;
    }
    private:
    Team* team_;
};

class Trainer {
    Team* Team_;
};
int main()
{
    Player player1;
    Team team1;
    std::vector<Player*> playerlist;
    player1.setteam_(&team1);
    playerlist = team1.get_playerlist();
    std::cout << playerlist.size();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

In the main there is player1 created and assigned to the playerlist of team1, now he should somehow appear there when i get the playerlist. But the output of this code is that the size of the playerlist of team 1 is still 0. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
player1.setteam_(&team1);
```

What happens next is:

```
void setteam_(Team* x){
    team_ = x;
}
```

Here you are stating that this `Player` has pointer to `Team` set to the same address as `x`. But this doesn't mean that this `Team` object has pointer to player in `std::vector`. This doesn't happen automaticly, you need something like:

```
void setteam_(Team* x){
    team_ = x;
    x->addPlayer( this);  // add to vector
}
```

Comment: thx nice solution, it works ;)  never have seen "this" before.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Team` class has no method that actually adds players to the `player_` vector.  Setting the `team_` pointer to the `team1` instance is not sufficient.