# Interaction of pointers and classes

Tags: c++

Okay, i have some problems with pointers and classes.

Player1 is created and stored to the playerlist of team1, this works well(That was my question on my last post).

But now i have a new and different problem.
I want to set the name of player1 with the  help of the set_playername function of the playerclass. But I dont know how to adress it in the playerlist. playerlist[0] does not work, it seems to be a **Player object (This is what the compiler told me at some point).

In the code you see my try to get out something of the playerlist, but all i got were some cryptic symbols

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Player;
class Trainer;
class Team {
    Trainer* trainer_;
    std::vector<Player*> player_;
public:
    std::vector<Player*> player() { return player_; }
    Trainer* trainer() { return trainer_; }

    std::vector<Player*> get_playerlist(){
        return player_;
    }
    void addPlayer(Player* x){
        player_.emplace_back(x);

    }

};

class Player {
public: 

    void setteam_(Team* x){
        team_ = x;
        x->addPlayer(this);
    }
    void setname_(std::string x){
        name_ = x;
    }
    std::string getname_(){
        return name_;
    }
    private:
    Team* team_;
    std::string name_;
};


class Trainer {
    Team* Team_;
};
int main()
{
    Player player1;
    Team team1;
    std::vector<Player*> playerlist;
    player1.setteam_(&team1);
    playerlist = team1.get_playerlist();
    std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
    printf("%s", a);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

How to adress the player stored in playerlist by some pointers ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classes accessing each other with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337801/classes-accessing-each-other-with-pointers)

Comment: this is not quite the same question but belongs to this topic, yes. I thought new questions should be asked in a new post ?

Comment: Do you realize that you didn't set the name of the player?

Comment: I did, i  want to set the name afterwards by adressing the player in the playerlist with the set_name function but can't figure out how to do it

Comment: No idea why are you doing this, but this is the code that does what you want:
playerlist[0]->setname_("name");

Comment: no it doesn't work as playerlist[0] is only some pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this issue:

> In the code you see my try to get out something of the playerlist, but all i got were some cryptic symbols

is that the following code is bad:

```
std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
printf("%s", a);
```

`printf` is a varargs function, where the type of the second (and subsequent) parameters is determined at run-time from the format string. By passing it `"%s"` you are saying the next argument will be a `char *`, but instead you are passing it a `std::string`. This is "bad".

You could extract the `char *` from the string and pass it to `printf` like this:

```
std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
printf("%s", a.c_str());
```

or use the C++ printing functions instead:

```
std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
std::cout<<a;
```

In both cases you may want a newline too:

```
std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
printf("%s\n", a.c_str());
```

or

```
std::string a=(*playerlist[0]).getname_();
std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
```

Note that as you've not yet set the player names, you'll get the empty string - but that is a seperate issue.

You can do that as follows:

```
playerlist[0]->setname_("name");
```

or

```
(*playerlist[0]).setname_("name");
```

Comment: nice answer, really helped me a lot in understanding what i did wrong !

Comment: @jimbo999 the primary error was that you didn't initialize the Player name at all

Comment: Yes i had it in my code before at some time but after playing around and deleting some lines i somehow deleted this line, too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the name of the `Player` if you are to use it:

```
class Team {
    Trainer* trainer_;
    std::vector<Player*> player_;
public:
    std::vector<Player*>& player() { return player_; }
                        ^
                        // no copy
    Trainer* trainer() { return trainer_; }
    std::vector<Player*>& get_playerlist(){
                        ^
                        // no copy
        return player_;
    }
    void addPlayer(Player* x){
        player_.push_back(x);

    }

};
```

And you should be using

```
std::cout<<s; // s is std::string (see below)
```

or

```
printf("%s",s.c_str());
```

to print the name.

`printf` is not type safe since it uses variable arguments in the C sense. `printf` has no option for `std::string`, only a `C`-style string. Using something else in place of what it expects is *undefined behavior*.

```
int main()
{
    Player player1;
    Team team1;

    player1.setname_( std::string("player1"));
               ^ // !
    player1.setteam_(&team1);
    std::vector<Player*>& playerlist = team1.get_playerlist();
                        ^  // no copy
    Player* pp = playerlist[0];
    std::string s = pp->getname_();
    std::cout<<s; // or printf("%s",s.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx I inserted this into my code with an extra printf("%s",s)but the output is still crazy signs and not the expected "player1"

Comment: @jimbo999 printf("%s",s.c_str()); but you shoud use printf to print char, and cout<< to print std::string